# "early in the morning" and " in the early morning"

Tags: syntactic-analysis, adverb-position

Is there any difference between the two phrases ?

1. There are numerous health benefits of drinking water on an empty stomach in the early morning.
2. There are numerous health benefits of drinking water on an empty
   stomach early in the morning.

Comment: Not much difference that I can think of.

Comment: In your context there is little or no difference but there are differences which show in other contexts. For example I would tend to say "I got up early in the morning yesterday" because it refers to a specific occasion and time in the morning; but I would be more likely to say "I like walking in the woods in the early morning" as that refers to repeated activity which can take place at different times depending on the time of year. This doesn't mean that the terms are _never_ used in the opposite context, just that there is a strong tendency to use them in the way I suggest.

Comment: I'd say "early in the morning" is a little more flexible based on your schedule. "in the early morning" -> I should get up at 5 just to drink some water. "early in the morning" -> I should drink some water shortly after I get up at 10:30.

Comment: I will note that there's a difference between "in the early morning rain" and "early in the morning rain".

Comment: In #1, you first determine the period called "early morning" and do something then. In #2, you determine the period called "morning", and do something in the "early" part of that period.

Comment: @Kevin Absolutely.

Comment: I think it should be "benefits **to**."

Comment: In 1, early is an adjective, in 2. it is an adverb. In 1. the morning is early, and in 2. the drinking can be construed as early.

Comment: early in the morning is written or spoken but "in the early morning", unless questioned by a lawyer on the stand, is quite unusual.

Answer (score 2):

In context, there is very little in the way of practical differences in semantic meaning here.

Linguistically, this demonstrates an interesting phenomenon, which might be underlying your intuition that there is a difference between these two sentences (if indeed you get this intuition). This is an example of the difference in modifier scope (a term borrowed from [logical quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(logic))). Essentially, what this means is that the modifier *early* is taking **scope** over two different parts (or constituents) of the sentence. Notice that in (1) the relevant string is *early morning*, where *early* is acting as an adjective modifier to the noun *morning*. However, in (2), the relevant string is *early in the morning* where *early* is acting as a temporal adverbial modifying the temporal phrase *in the morning*.

What does this mean, though, in more concrete terms? If, for instance, you consider *early morning* to be the time between 5 am and 7 am. Under the reading offered in (1), where you are to drink water in early morning, you are following this advice if you drink water between 5 am and 7 am. However, the reading in (2) makes no such restriction. As long as you drink water early *sometime* within the morning, say 8 am (if that is sufficiently early enough), you are following the advice given in the two sentences.

Answer (score 0):

May we assume the common bits make no difference and you're actually asking for a comparison of 'in the early morning' and 'early in the morning'?

No. There is no significant difference.